# Formula for calculating for export capacity for an ADX cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer

As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/capacitypolicy#export-capacity) "The cluster's total export capacity, as shown by .show capacity, is calculated by"

Export capacity = `Minimum(ClusterMaximumConcurrentOperations, Number of nodes in cluster * Maximum(1, Core count per node * CoreUtilizationCoefficient))`

Here is my cluster configuration:-

```
Cluster Nodes = 6
Core count per node = 16 ( since I am using Standard_D14_v2)
ClusterMaximumConcurrentOperations for ExportCapacity = 100
CoreUtilizationCoefficient for Export Capacity = 0.25
```

So by plugging these values into the formula I get value as 24:-

```
Export capacity = Minimum(100, Number of nodes in cluster * Maximum(1,16*0.25))
                = Minimum(100, 6 * 4)
                = 24
```

But when I issue `.show capacity` command , I see the '`Total`' column showing the value 20 for 'DataExport' resource. Why 20, when it should be 24 as per the formula ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the note below in the same document you linked to. Number of nodes considered for capacity in your case are 5 and not 6. Although the note mentions ingest operations, this is relevant for export capacity as well:

[image]